# MVC actionfilter attribute redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

I am creating a `actionfilter` to check user session but when i run webpage shows the following message

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

here is the code

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["authenticate"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "Login" } });
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

**Controller code**

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Admin/
       [CustomActionFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

this function is called again and again

**note: i am newbie to `actionfilters`**

Comment: You never set the value of `Session["authenticate"]` so you get an endless loop (it redirects to /Account/Login, sees that the value is null, then redirects to /Account/Login, sees that the value is null, then redirects .....). What is the point of this attribute?

Comment: point is: if user is not authenticated it is redirected to login page

Comment: Use the inbuilt features of MVC (using `[Authorize]` attribute). I suggest you work through the tutorials on the [MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc) - the section on Security, Authentication and Authorization

Comment: Is the `CustomActionFilter` also applied to `Login` action?

Comment: @shakib no not on Login Screen